# flashing yocto image to raspberrypi cm3 eMMC

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto

I have build a yocto image for raspberrypi cm3 and i want to flash it to the eMMC.
In the deploy/images/raspberrypi-cm3 directory a don't have a .img file that would be flashed and also how can i knew if my image will boot directly when starting. 
actually this is the first time i work with yocto and the first time i flash an image to a board.
THis is my deploy/image directory content.
I will be greatful if someone explains it to me.
thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xjJv.png)

---

Thank youf or the answer.
As i understanded, the mount command line is to create a disk image and makes it readable by the system. So after copying all image directory to it and unmounted it, what would i have in the 'if' option when i will flash my image with 'dd if=/home/user/deploy/images/raspberry-cm3 of=/dev/mmcblk1 '.

Also when a tried to mount the disk image 'sudo mount -o loop raspberry-cm3.img /media/raspberry-cm3/'.

error:mount: mount point /media/raspberry-cm3/ does not exist.

Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: Consider posting this question in [another](https://www.superuser.com) SE sister site.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

You can flash a image using Linux's `dd` command-line tool.

For example:

```
dd if=/home/user/deploy/images/raspberry-cm3 of=/dev/mmcblk1
```

Make sure you're using the correct device in the output (ie, make sure /dev/mmcblk1 is your eMMC card)

Edit: in order to flash, you'll need to generate an image. You can do it by creating an empty image, then mounting it as loop, then copying all the directory tree into the disk, and unmount it:

```
dd bs=512 count=2880 if=/dev/zero of=raspberry-cm3.img
mkfs.msdos raspberry-cm3.img
sudo mount -o loop raspberry-cm3.img /media/raspberry-cm3/
cp -r /deploy/images/raspberry-cm3/* /media/raspberry-cm3/
sudo umount /media/raspberry-cm3/
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understanded, the mount command line is to create a disk image and makes it readable by the system. So after copying all image directory to it and unmounted it, what would i have in the 'if' option when i will flash my image with 'dd if=/home/user/deploy/images/raspberry-cm3 of=/dev/mmcblk1 '. would it be 'dd if=/media/raspberry-cm3/ of=/dev/mmcblk1 ' ?